# How to split a string and grouping all the info into a map with duplication values using Java 8 Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following string:

```
"id1:name1,id2:name1,id3:name2,id4:name2,id5:name2"
```

and I want to convert this string into a map of the following form:

```
{name2=[id3, id4, id5], name1=[id1, id2]}
```

My requirement is the same as this question: [How to split a string into a map with a list of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740710/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-map-with-a-list-of-values) However, how can I do this using **Java 8 Stream API**?

Comment: Have you at least tried anything?

Comment: you should put your wrong code first. rather than let's solve your assignment.

Comment: Yes, I can group the item into a map without duplication. But what I want is that the duplicated ids should be grouped into a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on tags you are looking for stream solutions. Here is one

```
String text = "id1:name1,id2:name1,id3:name2,id4:name2,id5:name2";
Map<String, List<String>> map = Arrays
        .stream(text.split(","))
        .map(pair -> pair.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    pair -> pair[1], 
                    Collectors.mapping(e -> e[0], Collectors.toList())
                )
        );

System.out.println(map);
```

Output: `{name2=[id3, id4, id5], name1=[id1, id2]}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "id1:name1,id2:name1,id3:name2,id4:name2,id5:name2";
    String[] pairs = input.split(",");
    Map<String, String> result = Stream.of(pairs)
            .map(pair -> pair.split(":"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    splittedPair -> splittedPair[1], // to key function (extracts name)
                    splittedPair -> splittedPair[0], // to value function ( extracts id)
                    (id1, id2) -> id1 + "," + id2)); // in case of same name merges id

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The output is following: {name2=id3,id4,id5, name1=id1,id2}

If you need as a result `Map<String, List<String>>` you can use following collector:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = Stream.of(pairs)
        .map(pair -> pair.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            splittedPair -> splittedPair[1],
            splittedPair -> {
                List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
                ids.add(splittedPair[0]);
                return ids;
            },
            (idList1, idList2) -> {
                idList1.addAll(idList2);
                return idList1;
            }));
```

Comment: There is a more concise way: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/fb2729899682abe388a4dfd8e762c3e1

Comment: @JBNizet I totally agree ;) That was the first that came to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a simpler way by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
StreamEx.of(text.split(",")).map(p -> p.split(":"))
                            .mapToEntry(p -> p[1], p -> p[0]).grouping();
```